# How to add doube quotes to values using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

In my code I'm writing my records from a MySQL DB to a csv file, and this correctly works. What I'm trying to do now is wrap each single value inside double quotes but I can't find anything to perform this except concatenating double quotes to each value in the `rowMapper`. Is there anything faster ? I'm using a `FlatFileItemWriter` for write on file.

Comment: Show your code what you have done.

Comment: `String quotedRow='"' + rowValue+'"';` ?? I think that is fastest possible way.

Comment: My DTO which get each row is pretty long and complicated since attributes are not Strings. I was wondering if there was something like this during the writing phase but surfing on the web i can't find anything related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by faster? You can indeed do it in the row mapper, but I think it is better to do it in an item processor as this is a typical use case for an item processor (transforming data).

Comment: @ZhaledAsufian If you have found a way out for doing this, please post an answer to this question. I need to do exactly the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the line tokenizer.

```
@Bean
public DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA);
    lineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    return lineTokenizer;
}
```

Comment: I can't see an option to set the line tokenizer on the `FlatFileItemWriter`. How can I ensure that the line tokenizer is actually used?

Comment: That is because you do not set the tokenizer on the item writer.  It is set on the line mapper.

Comment: His question is how to write values with quotes, not how to read values with quotes.

Comment: And this addresses that.   There is nothing about the line tokenizer attached to only reading or writing.

Answer (score -1):

Use au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter from Open CSV.

Dependency for OpenCSV

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Create the writer with this constructor.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(rptFileName), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```